# Error: Cannot call value of non-function type

Tags: swift, xib

I am trying to make an extension of  `UIViewController` `nib` registration.

So instead of `PastOrdersViewController(nibName: "PastOrdersViewController", bundle: nil)` we can do something like

```
extension UIViewController {
 func loadNib(vc: UIViewController,nibName: String) -> UIViewController{
        return vc(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)//Error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIViewController'
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error:-

> Error:Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIViewController'

Comment: Why are you passing a view controller? Are you trying to pass a view controller type and get an instance of that type?

Comment: I am looking for solution like `PastViewController.loadNib` @RakeshaShastri

Comment: How does method make it any smaller? It's already a single line code. The only thing you will be reducing is a parameter if the nibBundle is nil. Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to dry the code, How can we make ?

Comment: I do not understand.

Comment: This is not a dry, you're adding a new method that has the same amount of parameters. Plus that you loose the type safety since the result of your method is a generic `UIViewController`, while the `init` approach returns a reference to the subclass. No longer having to write `bundle: nil` doesn't add much value with this approach.

Comment: @Cristik right!, but still thinking is there possible way ?

Comment: @Ramesh see my answer ;)

Comment: I don't know why Downvote. @Cristik solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs from the fact that the `vc` parameter points to an instance of `UIViewController`, and from how the method looks like you want to instead call the initializer on the controller class.

You could use `Self`, and drop the first argument, this will make the `loadFromNib` method really simple. Another optimization that you could make would be to declare the nib name as optional, and give it a default value of `nil`:

```
extension UIViewController {
    static func loadFromNib(_ nibName: String? = nil) -> Self {
        return self.init(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
    }
}
```

You'd then be able to nicely use the method like this:

```
let vc = MyViewController.loadFromNib() // loads from MyViewController.nib
```

, or

```
let vc = MyViewController.loadFromNib("Custom") // loads from Custom.nib
```

Comment: Cheers :) thats what I am looking for